# In my android studio I am not able to attach my debugger

Tags: android, adb

I tried adb stop-server, start-server but its not helping.
i am able to access device logcat but debugger is not stoping at debug point.
device shows as waiting for debugger with force close option.
if anyone can help  I'd really appreciate your help and insight.

Comment: Restarting Studio sometimes helps

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have tried all below troubleshooting steps:

1. Android Studio invalid cache and restart
2. ADB kill-server and then ADB start-server
3. Clean build and install on your device or emulator
4. Device/Emulator restart
5. Android developer settings USB debugging switch it off then On again.